# zend form captcha problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am using zend captcha in zend form. it's working properly, but when it creates then it generate this code:

```
<img width="80" height="30" alt="Allindia captcha" src="/allindiazend/public/images/captcha/4ae305b05406c9d8b06a19ea7ff2c9d9.png"/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="captcha[id]" value="4ae305b05406c9d8b06a19ea7ff2c9d9" title="Security Check." id="captchas" />
<input type="text" name="captcha[input]" id="captchas" value="" title="Security Check." />
```

The text box is occur below the img due to this `<br/>`. I dont want this 'br' tag in the generated code.

this is my code for captcha:

```
$captcha= new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
                'id'=>'captchas',
                'title'=>'Security Check.',
                'captcha' => array(
                'captcha' => 'Image',
                'required' => true,
                'font'=>'arial.ttf',
                'wordlen'=>'4',
                'width'=>'80',
                'height'=>'30',
                'ImgAlign'=>'left',
                'imgdir'=>'public/images/captcha',
                'DotNoiseLevel'=>'0',
                'LineNoiseLevel'=>'0', 
                'Expiration'=>'1000',
                'fontsize'=>'16',
                'gcFreq'=>'10',
                'ImgAlt'=>'Allindia captcha',
                'imgurl'=>'/allindiazend/public/images/captcha',
                'GcFreq'=>'5'
                )));
```

can any one help me plz.

Comment: Did you change any decorators that your captcha is generating such html?

Comment: I didn't attach any decorator. it generate <br/> automatically.

Comment: There are default decorators loaded for each Zend_Form_Element. See my answer, how you can find out, which they are.

Comment: The reason I asked is that I checked the html generated for zend captcha at my zf project, and it does not contain any `<br />`. I use ZF 1.11.0.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't have to do anything with the configuration of the captcha itself, but with the form-element. I guess that this `<br />` is added in any of the default decorators of `Zend_Form_Element_Captcha`. Look which decorators are attached to the form like this:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($captcha->getDecorators()); echo '</pre>'; exit;
```

You'll see all decorators. Try removing all decorators step by step to see which of them generates the `<br />`. Remove it completly or if it is necessary override it with your own decorator omitting the `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this

```
foreach($this->getElements() as $element) {
    $element->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
        ->removeDecorator('Label')
        ->addDecorator('Label');
}
```

gets rid of the default Decorators and creates blank ones